# How to display single choice AlertDialog with custom views?

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I need to make custom AlertDialog with single choice, but without radio buttons and with two custom TextViews in each item. I've try to use AlertDialog:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> items=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
//..here I fill my ArrayList
SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter=new SimpleAdapter(this, items, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {"name","count"}, new int[] {R.id.name,R.id.count});

AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
alert.setSingleChoiceItems(simpleAdapter, -1, new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        //Here I handle click
    }});
alert.show();
```

But it doesn't close after click on item. Why? May be I can fix it?

Alternatively, I've try to use Dialog for it:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> items=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
//..here I fill my ArrayList
SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter=new SimpleAdapter(this, items, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {"name","count"}, new int[] {R.id.name,R.id.count});

Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

View view=LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.items_list, null);
ListView listView=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        //Here I handle click
        dialog.dismiss();
    }});

dialog.setContentView(view);
dialog.show();
```

But it have problem with styles and text doesn't showing (text color coincide with background color).

I think that AlertDialog preferably for me. But how to make it?

Comment: From the documentation for the `setSingleChoiceItems` method: *.... Clicking on an item in the list will not dismiss the dialog. ...*

Comment: Ohh... But how to implement it?

Comment: `((Dialog) arg0).dismiss();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it doesn't close after click on item. Why? May be I can fix it?

The [`AlertDialog.Builder.setSingleChoiceItems`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setSingleChoiceItems%28java.lang.CharSequence%5B%5D,%20int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29) method will not dismiss the dialog by default so you have to do it manually. To do this, you just need to cast the `DialogInterface` parameter of the `onClick` callback(representing the dialog itself) to a `Dialog` and use the `dismiss()` method:

```
((Dialog) arg0).dismiss();
```